# Falha no carregamento de script com angular (ng-view)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design

Estou fazendo um projeto com angular js e utilizando o material design lite (mdl) para o layout. Algumas features do mdl necessitam de um arquivo javascript para funcionar porém esse arquivo tem ora que carrega, ora não. Acredito que o navegador acaba carregando o arquivo javascript do mdl antes do angular carregar o conteudo na ng-view. Alguém sabe como posso corrigir isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quem passar por este problema, segue a solução.

Na tag script, que importa o javascript do mdl insira o atributo **defer**.

Além disso utilizei uma directive para fazer o upgrade das tags html que necessitam do script do mdl:

```
function mdlUpgrade($window, $timeout) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function () {
          return {
            post: function postLink(scope, element) {
              $timeout(function () {
                if (angular.isDefined($window.componentHandler)) {
                  $window.componentHandler.upgradeElements(element[0])
                }
              }, 0);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```